# Open and Close a div by click on link and close by X button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created and it works perfectly ok But it only runs for one time, Means by clicking on a "Subscribe to Trade Alert" link a div box opens and says subscribe and have an x mark to close that div, but after closing If I again open a div by clicking a same link it is not working for the second time. I want it to run infinite.

heres the code:

```css
.trade-alert
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
}

.subscription-trade-alert-box
{
    width: 423px;
    height: 177px;
    border: 1px solid #DAE2ED;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(83,100,122,.35);
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}

.close
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.scc-trade-alert-tips
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #1686CC;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.tips-icon-mail
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(images/mail-ta.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.trade-alert-focus-anchor:focus .subscription-trade-alert-box
{
    display: block;
    
    
}
```

```html
<a class="trade-alert-focus-anchor" href="#">
      <div class="trade-alert">
        <div class="scc-trade-alert-tips">
          <i class="tips-icon-mail" ></i>
          Subscribe to Trade Alert
        </div>
      </div>
                                            
      <div class="subscription-trade-alert-box">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        Subscribe
      </div>
      
      <script>
        var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
        var i;
                                                
        for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
        closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        });
        }
      </script>
</a>
```

How to make this infinite open and close.

Comment: How is the modal being opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it that it opens multiple times without changing to much:
1st I changed the Box `subscription-trade-alert-box` to an ID instead of a class.
2nd I fixed the change from Class to ID in CSS
3rd I added an onclick event for the subscription link
4th added a JS line that the subrcription box style dispaly: block is set when clicked.

```js
        var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
        var i;
                                                
        for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
        closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        });
        }

function showBox() {
    document.getElementById("subscription-trade-alert-box").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.trade-alert
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
}

#subscription-trade-alert-box
{
    width: 423px;
    height: 177px;
    border: 1px solid #DAE2ED;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(83,100,122,.35);
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}

.close
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.scc-trade-alert-tips
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #1686CC;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.tips-icon-mail
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(images/mail-ta.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.trade-alert-focus-anchor:focus #subscription-trade-alert-box
{
    display: block;
    
    
}
```

```html
<a class="trade-alert-focus-anchor" href="#">
  <div class="trade-alert">
    <div class="scc-trade-alert-tips" onclick="showBox()">
      <i class="tips-icon-mail" ></i>
      Subscribe to Trade Alert
    </div>
  </div>
                                            
  <div id="subscription-trade-alert-box">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    Subscribe
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using classes. You didn't fix anything, you just changed it...

Comment: of course you can use a class but this becomes more compliacted espacially if you ahve more then just one element with that class. therefor the ise of an ID is the smarter solution. Then you will only adress that div with JS (getElementByID) and use ID.style.display and change the value to none/block or hidden/visible

Comment: I would argue classes are a smarter solution when you get into more complicated layouts, with a proper hierarchy and naming schema. Also, adding an ambiguously named function isn't good practice. Now the next person (or your future self) has to dig through the code to figure out what `box` is being referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick event in javascript instead of :focus in css.

```
  <div class="trade-alert">
    <div class="scc-trade-alert-tips" onclick="document.getElementById('subscription-trade-popup').style = 'display: block;'">
      <i class="tips-icon-mail"></i>
      Subscribe to Trade Alert
    </div>
  </div>
                                        
  <div class="subscription-trade-alert-box" id="subscription-trade-popup">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    Subscribe
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `.style = 'none'` at the element level, it overrules the css level rule. Instead, you can remove the css rule and simply add another event listener to toggle the style between `block` and `none`.

Also, I'd reccomend using [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), as they are the modern standard for selecting elements.

```css
.trade-alert
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
}

.subscription-trade-alert-box
{
    width: 423px;
    height: 177px;
    border: 1px solid #DAE2ED;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(83,100,122,.35);
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}

.close
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.scc-trade-alert-tips
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #1686CC;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.tips-icon-mail
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(images/mail-ta.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* remove this
.trade-alert-focus-anchor:focus .subscription-trade-alert-box
{
    display: block;
    
    
}
*/
```

```html
<a class="trade-alert-focus-anchor" href="#">
      <div class="trade-alert">
        <div class="scc-trade-alert-tips">
          <i class="tips-icon-mail" ></i>
          Subscribe to Trade Alert
        </div>
      </div>
                                            
      <div class="subscription-trade-alert-box">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        Subscribe
      </div>          
</a>

<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.close').forEach(function(close) {
    close.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation(); //otherwise the click will bubble and reopen itself
      this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });

  document.querySelector('.trade-alert-focus-anchor')
   .addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.querySelector('.subscription-trade-alert-box')
       .style.display = 'block';
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript adds styles as inline css. So if you add a style with JS then also remove it with JS. This line is adding the `display: none;` as an inline style,

```
this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
```

I made a codepen where I used JS to open and close the popup/modal, by assigning `display: block` to show and `display:none;` to hide.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/shamsad-anam/pen/QWNoGMd)